# 64 bit mode pixel outputting does not work (mov es, ax) vm crashes

Tags: assembly, x86-64, osdev

So I switched directly to 64-bit mode because it was easier. But I want to output pixels, and the command move es, ax crashes my computer (a key part of the pixel output code). And I realized that there are traces of paging at the start of the code, so now I'm totally confused. I'm trying to make it BIOS-free, multi-platform, and basically compatible with everything. And if the code already has paging set up for me, that would make my life a lot easier. Then I just need to make it compatible with all monitors, have it detect the keyboard and mouse, and I'm all set. (I already programmed a language for it i just didn't want to include it because it's long.)
So here is the code:

```
%define FREE_SPACE 0x9000

ORG 0x7C00
[bits 16]
   mov ax,115h ; init 800x600 32bit
   mov     bx,ax
   mov     ax,4f02h
   int     16

Main:
   jmp 0x0000:.FlushCS               


.FlushCS:   
   xor ax, ax


   mov ss, ax
 
   mov sp, Main

   mov ds, ax
   mov es, ax
   mov fs, ax
   mov gs, ax
   cld

   call CheckCPU                     
   jc nlm


   mov edi, FREE_SPACE

   jmp SwitchToLongMode

nlm:



BITS 16


%define PAGE_PRESENT    (1 << 0)
%define PAGE_WRITE      (1 << 1)

%define CODE_SEG     0x0008
%define DATA_SEG     0x0010

ALIGN 4
IDT:
   .Length       dw 0
   .Base         dd 0

SwitchToLongMode: 
   push di
   mov ecx, 0x1000
   xor eax, eax
   cld
   rep stosd
   pop di

   lea eax, [es:di + 0x1000]        
   or eax, PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE
   mov [es:di], eax 



   lea eax, [es:di + 0x2000]         
   or eax, PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE 
   mov [es:di + 0x1000], eax         



   lea eax, [es:di + 0x3000]         
   or eax, PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE 
   mov [es:di + 0x2000], eax         


   push di                          
   lea di, [di + 0x3000]             
   mov eax, PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE    



.LoopPageTable:
   mov [es:di], eax
   add eax, 0x1000
   add di, 8
   cmp eax, 0x200000               
   jb .LoopPageTable

   pop di 


   mov al, 0xFF                
   out 0x21, al

   nop
   nop

   lidt [IDT]                       


   mov eax, 10100000b 
   mov cr4, eax

   mov edx, edi  
   mov cr3, edx

   mov ecx, 0xC0000080
   rdmsr    

   or eax, 0x00000100
   wrmsr

   mov ebx, cr0
   or ebx,0x80000001
   mov cr0, ebx                    

   lgdt [GDT.Pointer]

   jmp CODE_SEG:LongMode



GDT:
.Null:
   dq 0x0000000000000000

.Code:
   dq 0x00209A0000000000         
   dq 0x0000920000000000
ALIGN 4
   dw 0

.Pointer:
   dw $ - GDT - 1
   dd GDT


[BITS 64]      
LongMode:
   mov ax, DATA_SEG
   mov ds, ax
   mov es, ax
   mov fs, ax
   mov gs, ax
   mov ss, ax

; --------------------------------
mainl0: mov ax,10
   mov bx,10
   mov ecx,00000000111111111111111110001000b ;color
l0: ;edx : y edx : x
mov eax, 800
mov edx, 1
imul edx
add eax, edx
add eax, edx


mov edx, 3
imul edx
add eax, edx

   mov di,ax       ; di = eax % FFFFh (offset)
   mov ax,0A000h   ; es = A000h
   mov es,ax ;crash <----

mov eax,ecx    
  stosd           


   jmp l0


   hlt
   lol:
jmp lol
[bits 16]

CheckCPU:

   pushfd

   pop eax
   mov ecx, eax  
   xor eax, 0x200000 
   push eax 
   popfd

   pushfd 
   pop eax
   xor eax, ecx
   shr eax, 21 
   and eax, 1
   push ecx
   popfd 

   test eax, eax
   jz nlm

   mov eax, 0x80000000   
   cpuid                 

   cmp eax, 0x80000001
   jb nlm

   mov eax, 0x80000001  
   cpuid                 
   test edx, 1 << 29
   jz nlm

   ret



times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

I know that this is long and dry, but I'm really trying to get this as low leveled as possible to make it compatible with everything, and to make it run smoothly.

Comment: Erm, you know that 64 bit long mode does not use the same address calculation as real mode, right? You have a flat memory model so just do `mov [0a0000h+eax], ecx`.

Comment: The segment registers don't really exist in 64-bit mode (fs and gs "sort of" still do, but not the others), so you can't write to them; it makes no sense.

Comment: @ChrisDodd You can of course still change segment registers.  Their contents will just be ignored for memory accesses.  Selected instructions may still make use of them.  CS is of course still used to select operating mode and ring.  Segment limit may be checked on some CPUs with some feature flags enabled.

Comment: Your GDT has one entry, but moving `0A000h` into ES tried to index entry `0A000h >> 3`, way beyond the GDT length limit you loaded with `lgdt`.  That's why it faults.  But you're in 64-bit mode, therefore CS/DS/ES/SS are all base=0, limit=unlimited, flat memory model, no need for that inconvenient real-mode stuff where you can't address all the memory at once.  And `stosd` uses 64-bit address-size, so it makes no sense to try to use 16-bit pointers; you literally can't do that in 64-bit mode.

Comment: "multi-platform" ??? The code will only run on the x64 platform.

Comment: @Jester Thank you! Now It works, but was i right about the paging? I mean, `es:di` and `PAGE_PRESENT` tells me that there is paging. But I want it interrupt free. And I'm new to the graphics part of assembly. And I somehow need to make it compatible with multiple resolutions (for now it's just 800x600 and VESA only supports up to 2100 I think but there are way bigger resolutions than that.)

Comment: For higher resolutions you will need to use linear framebuffer which is usually not at `a0000` so you will need to parse that from the mode info.

Comment: @Jester But how do i enter the linear framebuffer? There is no answers on the internet. And i need to be compatible with even 8k, basically like windows or any other operating system. And will i need paging after that?

Comment: It will not be compatible with 8k ... only with the modes your vesa bios supports. Other operating systems have their own graphics drivers. Paging is unrelated, but yes, it is mandatory in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @Jester Can I acces the GPU raw? I mean, no setting resolution, nothing, just setting directly the bytes to the colors what i want (24byte color mode). That way it could be compatible with even 8k.

Comment: GPUs are complicated beasts and each manufacturer and chip works differently which is why you need various drivers, especially since you said you wanted it to be "BIOS free" so you can't even rely on a vesa bios setting up a LFB for you.